# How to multiselect individual files by keyboard in Windows 11

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, user-interface

In all previous versions of windows, multiple files could be selected in Windows Explorer by holding the Control key, using the arrow keys to highlight each file and hitting Space over each file you want to select.

When you hold Control and hit Space over a file in Windows 11, instead of selecting the file, it opens a useless dialog called "WinUI Desktop" which shows some file details and a button to open the file in the default application.  To call this behavior very annoying is an understatement.

The best solution here would be to disable this behavior and re-enable the traditional UI behavior. If that's not possible, it would be helpful to know the recommended way to multi-select files in Windows 11.

(Note that holding Control and clicking the files still works as expected but the question is how to do this with keyboard only.  Likewise, it would also be possible to accomplish multi-select using the "Use checkboxes to select items" setting in the Folder Options but that cannot be turned on without changing the UI for all folders in the entire OS.)

Comment: You can also use the arrow keys to select a file, and then hold shift as you move the cursor. It will select everything from the first selected file to the one you currently have selected. Another option is CTRL-A to select everything if that is your ultimate goal.

Comment: That wasn't part of the question, but I see how one might think that from the title alone.  I improved the title by changing "multiselect files" to "multiselect individual files".  

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behavior on my Windows 11 VM you describe using the shortcut you want to use, i my experience, the same shortcut works on Windows 10 22H2 and Windows 11 23H2.  In other words CTRL+SPACE and CTRL+ALT+SPACE worked identically

Comment: See the new accepted answer below, it turns out it was being caused by the Peek feature of Windows Powertoys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the [Peek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/peek) feature of PowerToys. At least it is for me on Windows 10. The Peek feature can be deactivated or assigned a different keyboard shortcut in the PowerToys configuration.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  Thank you so much!

Comment: What's weird is that I never turned this feature on.  I use a very specific subset of PowerToys modules.  I wonder if it turned on automatically when they added the Peek feature?

Comment: @JasonL. I also don’t remember having turned it on. Maybe the 23H2 update did it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 11, you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to select multiple files.